# How do I calculate the number of molecules in an equilibrium depending on a change in the equilibrium constant?

Tags: equilibrium, stoichiometry

> Consider 1000 molecules of $\ce{A}$ and 1000 molecules of $\ce{B}$ in a eucaryotic cell. The concentration of both will be about $\pu{10^-9 M}$.
>   If the equilibrium constant $K$ for $\ce{A + B <--> AB}$ is $\pu{10^10}$, then at equilibrium there will be
>   \begin{array}{ccc}
>   \bbox[1ex,lightgreen]{270} 
>     & \bbox[1ex,lightgreen]{270} 
>     & \bbox[1ex,yellow]{730} \\
>   \ce{A} & \ce{B} & \ce{AB}\\
>   \text{molecules}&\text{molecules}&\text{molecules}\\
> \end{array}
>   If the equilibrium constant is a little weaker at $\pu{10^8}$, which represents a loss of $\pu{2.8 kcal/mol}$ of binding energy from the example above, or 2-3 fewer hydrogen bonds, then there will be
>   \begin{array}{ccc}
>   \bbox[1ex,lightgreen]{915} 
>     & \bbox[1ex,lightgreen]{915} 
>     & \bbox[1ex,yellow]{\phantom{0}85} \\
>   \ce{A} & \ce{B} & \ce{AB}\\
>   \text{molecules}&\text{molecules}&\text{molecules}\\
> \end{array}
>
> ---
>
> **[Figure 3-44 Molecular Biology of the cell 5/e (© Garland Science 2008)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCiF0.jpg)**

I don't understand how in the above figure, the number of molecules is calculated.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.se! This seems like a homework question. Please share your thoughts towards a solution otherwise it will be closed in accordance with our [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange). A "homework question" is any question whose value lies in helping you understand the method by which the question can be solved, rather than getting the answer itself.

Comment: I hope that my answer helps the person asking understand the methods used to solve this problem and others like it.

Answer (score 4):

Setting out the problem like this using an ICE table: 
\begin{array}{cccc}
  \text{species} & \ce{A}    & \ce{B}    & \ce{AB} \\\hline
  \text{I}       & 10^{-9}   & 10^{-9}   & 0       \\
  \text{C}       & -x        & -x        & +x      \\
  \text{E}       & 10^{-9}-x & 10^{-9}-x & x       \\
\end{array}

Where $\text{I}$ is the initial concentration, $\text{E}$ is the final concentration (concentration at equilibrium) and $\text{C}$ is the change in concentration.

This ICE table (Initial, Change, Equilibrium), is a standard method for solving these types of problems.

The equilibrium constant is defined as 
$$K = \frac{[\ce{AB}]}{[\ce{A}][\ce{B}]},$$ 
where these are the concentrations at equilibrium.

We have our equilibrium concentrations as set out by the problem. Both $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$ start out at a concentration of $10^{-9}M$ with their final concentrations being $\pu{10^-9 M} - x$ where $x$ is some change in the concentration.

Note, it mentions that 1000 molecules corresponds to a concentration of $\pu{10^-9 M}$. Therefore one can see that this corresponds to $10^{12}~\frac{\text{molecules}}{\pu{M}}$.
($\pu{1000 molecules} = \beta \cdot \pu{10^-9 M}$ where one can see $\beta$ has units $\frac{\text{molecules}}{\pu{mol}}$)

We can substitute into the expression for $K$ and noting that $[\ce{A}]=[\ce{B}]$

$$10^{10} = \frac{x}{(10^{-9}-x)^2}$$

I could not be bothered to work this out by hand, so Mathematica gives two values for $x$ as this is a [quadratic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDvZem.png):
\begin{align}
  x_1 &= \pu{7.3e-10 M}\\
  x_2 &= \pu{1.4e-9 M}
\end{align}

One can immediately see that $x_2$ is not a valid solution as it corresponds to a concentration of $\ce{AB}$ higher than 100% conversion.

Taking $x_1$ as the solution: $$\pu{7.3e-10 M} \times 10^{12}~\frac{\text{molecules}}{\pu{M}} = \pu{730 molecules}\text{ of }\ce{AB}$$

The same can be repeated for the second case where the equilibrium constant is given as $K=10^8$.

Comment: could you explain why we have to do the calculation in mol and then convert to molecule number. shouldn't the proportion of reacted/unreacted molecues stay the same since they represent kinda same thing?

Comment: also, in the 2nd example K >> 1 still. then how come we have less final product than  reactants?